# Argument passing of template class as an interface

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, interface

Here is my scenario:

```
class Container {};

class Papa {};

class Child: public Papa {};

void myFunction(Container<Papa> container);
```

Now I want to pass two different parameters to myFunction().

```
int main() 
{
    Container<Papa> papaContainer;
    Container<Child> childContainer;
    myFunction(papaContainer);
    myFunction(childContainer);  // this line is not working 
}
```

apparently I cannot do this.

> no suitable user-defined conversion from "Container<Child>" to "Container<Papa>"

What would be the solution for this case? How `Container<Papa>` can be used as interface here?

Comment: It's because templates are not covariant. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2206549/745468. One solution could be to make your myFunction also a template.

Comment: @SMeznaric thanks, template covariance was the term I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

This seems similar to this question here: [No Suitable User Defined Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880493/no-suitable-user-defined-conversion)
although that one is using numeric types. Is there anything in myFunction, or that myFunction returns that would need to differentiate Child from Papa?

Comment: No it is not similar to that question. Completely different question.